# Delete from STL list while using C++11 iterate syntax

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Erasing an element from a container while inside a range-based for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624686/erasing-an-element-from-a-container-while-inside-a-range-based-for-loop)

[Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it), can you delete from an STL list while iterating over it using the new `for( auto item : list )` syntax?

Here's a complete example (that crashes!)

```
#include <list>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  list<int> li;
  li.push_back( 4 ) ;
  li.push_back( 5 ) ;
  li.push_back( 6 ) ;
  for( auto num : li )
  {
    if( num == 5 )
      li.remove( num ) ;
    else
      printf( "%d\n", num ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or just use iterators again..

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Some iterators are invalidated when an object is removed but I suppose a list iterator need not be... It's been a while since I actually used lists myself, so I might be absolutely wrong as well . (What a shame you can't downvote comments.) I believe I was thinking that the amount of nodes would matter - but it doesn't have to in a linked list, does it.

Comment: @EsaLakaniemi: Might not need to be, and is not allowed to be.  That's one of the few redeeming qualities of `std::list`.

Comment: I'll just remove that comment as misinformation, then.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - Range based for does use iterators.  The iterator for the current position is being invalidated by the remove because it now points at a list node that's gone bye-bye.  It will then try to access "next" and nasal demons have been summoned!  That is of course assuming that the element being actually removed is the one the user intends...which is not guaranteed in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not.  Your example crashes because you use `li.remove(num)` incorrectly and internal for-loop iterator is invalidated.

`li.remove(num)` should be used not in loop but as standalone statement. List member function `remove` iterates through all elements of a list and removes ones equal to value.

Answer (score -5):

I would just enter your code into a compiler and see if it works.

Comment: And the most unhelpful answer of the year award goes to...