# Add elements to a vector during range-based loop c++11

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

I have used the new range-based for loop provided by C++11 standard and I came up with the following question: suppose that we iterate over a `vector<>` using the range-based `for`, and we add some element in the end of the vector during this iteration. Thus, when do the loop end?

For instance, see this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<unsigned> test({1,2,3});
    for(auto &num : test) {
        cout << num << " ";
        if(num % 2)
            test.push_back(num + 10);
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for(auto &num : test) 
        cout << num << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

I tested G++ 4.8 and Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang++) with "-std=c++11" flag, and the output is (for both):

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 11 13
```

Note that the first loop terminates in the end of original vector, although we add other elements to it. It seems that the for-range loop evaluate the container end in beginning only.
Is this, in fact, the correct behavior of range-for? Is it specified by the committee? Can we trust in this behavior?

Note that if we change the first loop by

```
for(vector<unsigned>::iterator it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it)
```

with invalid the iterators and come up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: though adding isn't erasing, this is a duplicate of [Erasing an element from a container while inside a range-based for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624686/erasing-an-element-from-a-container-while-inside-a-range-based-for-loop) because the answer there shows you what the standard says the range-for does - end is determined  and saved before the loop starts, and that saved value is used on subsequent iterations.

Comment: @KateGregory I would argue this is  not a duplicate because  removing the current element would be undefined behavior for all containers, but adding an element is only undefined behavior for  `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::unordered_set` and `std::unorderd_map`.

Comment: I had seem that question, by the behavior is slightly different. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @KateGregory This is not a duplicate. The answer is different - see mine below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No you cannot rely on this behaviour. Modifying the vector inside the loop results in undefined behaviour because the iterators used by the loop are invalidated when the vector is modified.

The range based for loop

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression) loop_statement
```

is essentially equivalent to

```c
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = std::begin(__range),
        __end = std::end(__range); 
        __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
            range_declaration = *__begin;
            loop_statement 
    }
}
```

When you modify the vector, the iterators `__begin` and `__end` are no longer valid and the dereferencing `__begin` results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks David. It is interesting note that my two pieces of code, although essentially equivalent, come up with very different results.

Comment: actually, you are missing the disctinction between

  for(auto _begin = r.begin(); _begin != r.end(); ++begin)

and

  for(auto _begin = r.begin(), _end = r.end(); _begin != _end; ++_begin)

(the cacheing of r.end())

And *that* is why your program does the impression of working! the iterator is pointing to an old version of the vector. Put a destructor in the contained objects and hilarity will ensue... :-D

Comment: _iterators used by the loop are invalidated when the vector is modified_ Not necessarily. If vector's capacity is large enough not to require reallocation, then all iterators remain valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on this behavior as long as vector's capacity is large enough, so reallocation is not required. This would guarantee validity of all iterators and references other than past-the-end iterator after call to `push_back()`. This is fine since `end()` was calculated only once at the beginning of the loop (see [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)).

In your case, you have to increase capacity of `test` vector to guarantee this behavior:

```
vector<unsigned> test({1,2,3});
test.reserve(5);
```

**EDIT**

Based on responses to [Is it legal to add elements to a preallocated vector in a range-based for loop over that vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35468207/219153), this is a case of undefined behavior. Release version built with gcc, clang and cl runs fine, but a debug version built with cl (Visual Studio) will throw an exception.