# Vector iterator incompatible after push_back() of a new object

Tags: c++, vector

I have an `Entity` class that all objects (`Missiles`, `Spacesship`, `Stars`, `Explosions`) inherit from and whenever instances of these classes are created, Entity's constructor adds 'this' to its vector list of all instances, just like this:

```
std::vector<Entity*> Entity::instances;
Entity::Entity()
{
    instances.push_back(this);
}
```

This worked fine, because I could just loop through every instance and execute its method via e->Render() or e->Update() etc.

What is weird is, it works everywhere else but in one specific place.
It works here:
Core.cpp

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    stars[i] = new Star();
    stars[i]->position.x = rand() % (screenWidth + 1);
    stars[i]->position.y = rand() % (screenHeight + 1);
    stars[i]->angle = rand() % 360;
    stars[i]->boundingbox.w = 2 + rand() % 7;
    stars[i]->boundingbox.h = stars[i]->boundingbox.w;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    meteorites[i] = new Meteorite();
    meteorites[i]->Spawn();
}
```

**BUT here** .. it pops 'vector iterators incompatible'

Meteorite.cpp

```
void Meteorite::TakeDamage()
{
    health -= 5;
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Missile* explo = new Missile();
        explo->position.x = position.x;
        explo->position.y = position.y;

        Spawn();
    }
}
```

I'm completely clueless - it's not as if I was creating these elements in a different than the usual way.

**#EDIT**
I think this is also important, Meteorite::Update() that detects collision and runs TakeDamage() where the instance is created:

```
for each (Entity* e in Entity::instances)
{
    if (e == this)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (e->entClass == "ENTITY_MISSILE")
    {
        Missile* m = (Missile*)e;
        if (abs(position.x - m->position.x) * 2 < (boundingbox.w + m-
                >boundingbox.w))
        {
            if (abs(position.y - m->position.y) * 2 < (boundingbox.h + m-
                    >boundingbox.h))
            {
                TakeDamage();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustinFinnerty I'm sorry but I don't understand your point.

Comment: What is happening to `explo`? It looks like it just leaks memory. So when `Missile` is constructed it calls `Entity()`? Are you meant to be calling `Spawn` on `explo`?

Comment: @Tas but I'm not calling Spawn() on explo, Spawn() is called on Meteorite.

Comment: I've updated my main post with code for collision detection, that runs TakeDamage which in return created the object that pops error.

Comment: `for each (Entity* e in Entity::instances)` -- Is this C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is C++, I was surprised it worked too.

Comment: @Netheous -- No, it is not C++.  It is some weird syntax that possibly a particular compiler supports.

Comment: But it works everywhere else, it worked for creation of objects.

Comment: *But it works everywhere else, it worked for creation of objects.* -- We have no context whatsoever in where, when, and how these functions are called.  That's what's missing in your post, a [mcve].

Comment: It is going to be near impossible to solve this without a [mcve]. You're in the best position to solve the problem, since you have the debugger etc. We don't get a runnable copy of the code unless you create a [mcve]. FWIW, nothing looks disastrous, but that's about the best we can do.

Comment: Also, this looks like the classic mistake of iterating over a container while changing the container you're iterating over.  That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `#define each` `#define in :` :)

Comment: @Netheous -- What is `Spawn`?  And also, how do we know that your type is `Missile`, thus doing the unsafe cast here `Missile* m = (Missile*)e;`?   If anything, you should be issuing a `dynamic_cast<>` to ensure you haven't made an error.

Comment: Thank you everyone, the replacement of for each with a regular for loop fixed the issue.

Comment: @PasserBy -- Yes, macros are evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you call [`push_back` on a `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), then iterators get invalidated (emphasis mine):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() **then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated**. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

So in your `for` loop when `TakeDamage` gets called, and you construct a `Missile` (which subsequently calls `Entity::Entity()` and `instances.push_back(this)`), you are invalidating your iterators.

You either need to loop via indices instead of iterators, or keep track of which objects need `TakeDamage()` called on them and call them after you're finished iterating, or create a copy of `instances` that you iterate on.

Note that I've never seen the syntax `for each (... in ...)` but presumably it's using iterators.

---

You mention that the code in the question is ran within `Meteorite::Update`, and you also mention that

> This worked fine, because I could just loop through every instance and execute its method via e->Render() or e->Update() etc.

It's VERY likely you're iterating over all `instances`, calling `Update`, and within that calling `TakeDamage` which is invalidating your `instances`. Calling `push_back` within `TakeDamage` while iterating over `instances` is definitely your issue.

Comment: Replacing it with what NL628 said below still pops same error.

Comment: @Netheous -- If what you're doing is what this answer suggests, then it is the problem.  You are altering the container that you're relying on being "stable" in that `for` syntax.  That will not work correctly.  As a matter of fact, you *cannot* alter the container that is specified in the range-based `for` loop when iterating, but you're doing so.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've also followed the suggestion that Tas gave.
I've created a bool collided = false;

Then inside the for loop, I'm checking whether or not collision happened - if so, set collided to true and break;

After for loop - run TakeDamage(); if collided.

Same error.

Comment: I have also tried executing TakeDamage() manually, without the entire for loop - same error.

Comment: If _just_ calling `TakeDamage` triggers the error, then consider updating your question to JUST do that, rather than including what is superfluous surrounding code. I stand by my answer that this is your problem, whether or not it's for the reasons I mention. Note in your question you mention that `Meteorite::Update` calls this code, but by chance is `Meteroite::Update` being called in a `for` loop on `instances`? You are definitely attempting to call `push_back` while iterating through `instances`.

Comment: @Tas, Yes - this was the issue, I've replaced every 'for each' with for( n : array ); and it fixed the issue.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: No worries. I edited my answer to include this information as well, since these comments may get cleaned up.

Comment: @Netheous -- Note that the bullet-point to take in all of this is what I mentioned.  If you're going to use a range-based `for` loop, you shouldn't change the container you're iterating over that's specified in the loop syntax.  [More reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076672/add-elements-to-a-vector-during-range-based-loop-c11)

Answer (score 0):

try: `for(Entity* e : Entity::instances)` instead of your `for each` thing

Comment: Same.

I truly think it's not the issue with object itself, I can create it elsewhere and it works perfectly.

Comment: As in what? The error is completely vague and points to no line except code of vector itself.

Comment: As in printing out a different number before and after each line of vector manipulation, and seeing the last number which prints out. Then, finding the exact line where the error happens.

Comment: try: 'for(Entity* e : Entity::instances)'

Comment: I don't think you can change while iterating...try this: for(auto it = Entity::instances.begin(); it!= Entity::instances.end(); it++)

Comment: I've also executed TakeDamage() manually without the loop at all, same error.