# inserting into the back of std::list during range based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, push-back, stdlist, for-range

I came across "*[Add elements to a vector during range-based loop c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076672/add-elements-to-a-vector-during-range-based-loop-c11)*", and wasn't surprised it's not allowed using `std::vector` because the append can invalidate iterators. However, inserting into `std::list` doesn't invalidate any of the iterators, so I was wondering if it would be allowed with `std::list` instead of `std::vector`.

e.g.

```
std::list<int> list({1});
for (int &cur : list)
{
    std::cout << cur << " ";
    if (cur < 10)
    {
        list.push_back(cur + 1);
    }
}
```

It seems to compile fine, but I'm worried it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: I believe it's well-defined, for what it's worth. Based on what [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) expands to, and the fact that, indeed, adding to `std::list` doesn't invalidate iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, inserting / removing elements of a `std::list` does not invalidate pointers, references, or iterators to elements, except for the removed element. Not even the end-iterator is changed or invalidated.

Thus, it is safe.

But as one has to carefully ponder about safety, it is still inadvisable.

Comment: Why the last comment after "_it is safe_"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is still inadvisable, as it depends on the fairly unique peculiarities of that specific container, and is thus susceptible to clumsy future refactoring.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about that specific container and you concluded that it is safe. I'd just leave it at that. "_Thus, it is safe, for `std::list`_".